# Cross-referencing in R bookdown makes the figure name incorrect

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference

I am producing plotly charts in Rmarkdown and give them name and caption. but as soon as I cross reference them in the document, their name is ruined.

**Here is the code:**

````
---
title: "Preliminary Statistics"
author: "Babak"
date: "6/28/2021"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    fig_caption: true
    
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    fig.width=9, 
    fig.height=5 ,
    message=FALSE, 
    warning=FALSE)
```

```{r Area_duplicate, fig.cap = "Area of duplicated and unique properties by municipality"}
<PLOT CODES>
```
Plot \@ref(fig:Area_duplicate) shows the area od duplicated properties in the dataset grouped by municipality.
````

**result:**

[screenshot of the caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMRc1.png)

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the underscore in the name with a "-".